# Корректная работа с памятью в Android

Tags: getview, android, java

Уже не раз сталкивался с проблемой утечек памяти, когда вылетает java.lang.OutOfMemoryError и в частности java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Bitmap Size Exceeds VM Budget.

Сейчас делаю листалку в галереи и столкнулся с этой ошибкой. С первым вариантом. Версия дроида 4.0.3(не до конца обновленный galaxy s2).

Сразу нагуглилось [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)  Сделал пару советов оттуда - результат такой же.
Посему вопрос для тех кто сталкивался и решал проблемы: как с этим боритесь вы?

*Что само интересное - ошибка вылетает на листании миниатюр, а на листании больших картинок все гуд!*

**UPD 1**
Убираю атрибут adjustViewBounds в ImageView элемента галереи и все листается без ошибок.

**UPD 2**
Код:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ThumbViewHolder holder;

    View view = convertView;
    if( convertView == null ){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(resId, null);
        holder = new ThumbViewHolder();
        ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        holder.img = img;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
         holder = (ThumbViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    //BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //opts.outWidth = 10;
    //opts.outHeight = 10;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(position));
    holder.img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    return convertView;
  }
```

без использования холдера тоже самое.

**UPD 3**
Нужно также отметить что картинки имею разрешение 992х1370. И таких картинок много.

**UPD 4**
Опция opts.inSampleSize = 2; при декодировании битмапа действительно помогла.
Все равно остается много вопросов.

Comment: если у тебя миниатюры отображаются в виде списка и ты писал свой адаптер, то вероятней всего - писал его неправильно и потому, когда картинка уходит за границы видимости экрана - она не не стирается из памяти и не перезаписывается, а просто занимает память и чем больше прокручиваешь, там меньше свободной памяти остается

Comment: делаем дамп и смотрим в него Mat'ом (анализатором памяти - http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). И обычно вредители сразу всплывают.

Comment: да, скорее всего проблема в любимом паттерне под дроид ViewHolder. Там статики и все они наполнены картинками и все в памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim, последняя время без мата вообще на код сложно смотреть =)

Comment: А как сделать дамп? Поставил опцию в eclipse.ini -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError и при падении никакого файла нет. К слову работаю на девайсе(не рутованном)

Comment: а дамп будет не при падении. А когда попросят. А просить нужно через ddms (там есть кнопка Dump HPROF file). После этого файлик нужно преобразовать в понятный mat'у утилитой hprof-conv (идет с sdk).

Comment: а где этот файлик лежит после кликания на эту кнопку? уже кликал)

Comment: он предложит сохранить его. Куда скажите, туда и сохранит. Но может просто свой процесс в списке не выбрали?

Comment: выбрал - нажимаю - ничего не происходит вообще

Comment: Если девайс медленный, а процесс сильно изгадил память, то это может занять какое-то долгое время  (у меня на некоторых девайсах было до минуты).
но стоит также и лог почитать. Там могут интересные вещи проскакивать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону `BitmapFactory.Options.inPurgeable=true` в этом случае при нехватке памяти битмап будет выгружаться на диск.

Мне это помогло.

P.S. Опция работает только начиная с API 4

**Update**

Есть еще другая полезная фича: `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize=2` - вдвое уменьшает размер битмапов:

> If set to a value > 1, requests the
> decoder to subsample the original
> image, returning a smaller image to
> save memory. The sample size is the
> number of pixels in either dimension
> that correspond to a single pixel in
> the decoded bitmap. For example,
> inSampleSize == 4 returns an image
> that is 1/4 the width/height of the
> original, and 1/16 the number of
> pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the
> same as 1. Note: the decoder will try
> to fulfill this request, but the
> resulting bitmap may have different
> dimensions that precisely what has
> been requested. Also, powers of 2 are
> often faster/easier for the decoder to
> honor.

Кроме этого рекомендую посмотреть в сторону метода: `Application.onLowMemory()` - там можно попробовать кое-что неиспользуемое выгрузить/закрыть и проч.

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас попробуем.

Comment: сейчас писать о api level 4 как то странно, учитывая, что по статистике гугла таких устройств около 0.3% :)

Comment: Не, не помогло. Но стало получше. Нет быстро падает.

Comment: Стало лучше, но все равно падает. Просто не так быстро.

Comment: @KoVadim кому как. Я до сих пор вынужден поддерживать в своих прогах старые API - приходится всяко-разно изворачиваться. Уже привычка смотреть на API level. С другой стороны вы наверное правы, пора форсировать прекращение поддержки старых версий.

Comment: Я поддерживаю API level 7. И то, планирую отказаться и подняться до 8.

Comment: По сути опция в вашем апдейте просто выходные размеры уменьшает.

Comment: @DroidAlex так и нужно, только BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize указывается не жёстко, а в зависимости насколько реальный размер картинки больше масштабируемой. То есть отношение сторон (округлённое)

Answer (score 0):

Я может чегото недопонял. Вы в список грузите большие картинки, просто масштабируя их под нужный размер? Если да, то:
нужно использовать inSampleSize подробно здесь: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
Ну и рециклинг обязательно. Будет работать медленнее зато эффективнее с памятью

Comment: нет, масштабирования нет. Просто приложение падает выдавая указанную ошибку.

Comment: опция opts.inSampleSize = 2; действительно помогло. Премного благодарен товарищу @Barmaley